# Why is this method with generic return not properly using the generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I have some code that i need to use multiple times so i wanted to put it in a method. The code is:

```
try
{
    //Create a list descriptor for GSON to use
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getType();

    //Get it out as a list
    List<MyClass> myClass = gson.fromJson( jsonString, listType );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I put this in a method like:

```
public static <T> List<T> getTypeAsList(String jsonString)
{
    try
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        //Create a list descriptor for GSON to use
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType();

        //Get it out as a list
        return gson.fromJson( jsonString, listType );
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I call that method like:

```
util.<MyClass>getTypeAsList( jsonString );
```

But when I do this, I get the error:

```
com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to MyClass
```

Why is it not getting the proper type? It works in the first code, just not in the generic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `T` is erased. That means the the generic method doesn't have `T`'s type information.

Normally a `TypeToken` is used to capture that type information, but it's verbose to instantiate one, and in your case you already know some of the information, namely that the you have a `List` of *some* type.

So you can create a utility method, to create a `ParameterizedType` with `ArrayList` as raw type, and an arbitrary `Type` as a type argument:

```
public static ParameterizedType listTypeWith(Type t) {
    Type[] actual = { t };
    return new ParameterizedType() {

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return ArrayList.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return actual;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<MyClass> result = gson.fromJson("[{s:'Hello'}]", listTypeWith(MyClass.class));
System.out.println(result); // [MyClass [s=Hello]]
```

Comment: When the file is compiled, the type is erased, so it doesn't know about `T` at runtime. But it is somehow inferring `T` as `StringMap`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @svasa It's not inferring `StringMap`, that's just the default. It gets a `ParameterizedType` where the type argument is non-concrete, it will just be called `T`, and gson can't use that.

Comment: @JornVernee Do you know why the type is erased? Is there any way to keep it from being erased?

Comment: @DonRhummy That is the implementation of Java's generics. One of the benefits is that you only need 1 version of the code, as opposed to _instantiating_ it from a template for every type you use it with. It also has low runtime cost, since the VM doesn't have to implicitly pass around the type information for type variables. The result is, in short, that if you need a type variable's type information, you have to pass it around manually.

Comment: @JornVernee Why is `StringMap` the default ? I might be missing something related to `gson`.

Comment: @svasa You'd really have to ask the implementers, but it makes sense if you look at a JSON object. A key is a name, and can be represented as a `String`, then the value is any `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to type erasure at compile time.

To explain it further - in first case

```
new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}
```

at compile an anonymous class will be generated with actual type `ArrayList<MyClass>`. On the other hand with generic call

```
  new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}
```

actually compiled anonymous class will recieve `ArrayList<Object>` as actual type. Thus gson uses default implementation(that is `StringMap`) to deserialize array elements

Comment: Type erasure is at run time.

Comment: Nope, type is erased while compiling, that's why it's not available at runtime. If it wasn't erased at compile time, there would be definitely an option to not erase it at runtime you know ;)

Comment: @Alexey Is there a way to keep it from being erased at compile time?

Comment: I see your point about erasure. @Don Rhummy, there's no way to prevent type erasure.